# change tick labels in sunflower plot in R

Tags: r, plot

Say i have the following data

```
A <- c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
B <- c("A","B","A","C","C","A","C","D","C","A")
X <- data.frame(A,B)

sunflowerplot(X$B ~ X$A,
              main = "Sunflower plot", 
              xlab = "TYPE A",
              ylab = "TYPE B",
              size = 0.25, cex.lab = 1.5, mgp = c(2.5,1,0))
```

then by referring to this link I want to change the vertical ticks to the `factors` of `B`

with refernce to this website

[axis and text editing](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/axes.html)

how does one use this code to change the labels

```
axis(2, at=NULL, labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `yaxt` argument to suppress the y-axis in `sunflowerplot()`.
See `?par`:

> yaxt
>
> A character which specifies the y axis type. Specifying "n" suppresses plotting.

```
sunflowerplot(X$B ~ X$A,
              main = "Sunflower plot", 
              xlab = "TYPE A",
              ylab = "TYPE B",
              size = 0.25, cex.lab = 1.5, mgp = c(2.5,1,0),
              yaxt="n")
axis(2, at=1:4, labels=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
```

[image: plot]